# CDATA gets removed before being sent

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, soap

I am making a soap call inside an angular application.

I need to pass CDDATA for a section of a payload for one of the calls

```
angular.forEach(contactsCollection, function (item, index) {
    contacts = contacts +
        '<c>' +
            '<f><![CDATA[' + item.FirstName + ']]></f>' +
            '<l><![CDATA[' + item.LastName + ']]></l>' +
            '<e><![CDATA[' + item.EMailAddress1 + ']]></e>' +
        '</c>'
});
```

the tool behind the soap request is [jquery.soap](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap) which works with an interceptor.

All the calls work fine but ones with CDATA get removed in the payload.

I can see the formation is correct when it being passed to the soap call. But my payload has every section correct except the contact bit:

```
<Contacts><c><f></f><l></l><e></e></c>....
```

Any clues?

its definitely jquery.soap thats doing this. as it happens in beforesend. just can't figure out what.
could this be as a result of some transformation?

---

The soap request is constructed like this for jquery.soap:

```
data: ['<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
    '<soap:Header>' +
    '<ServiceAuthHeader xmlns="http://xxx.cl.xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx/">' +
        '<Username>' + User.Send.Username + '</Username>' +
        '<Password>' + User.Send.Password + '</Password>' +
    '</ServiceAuthHeader>' +
    '</soap:Header>' +
    '<soap:Body>' +
    '<ContactBulkImportWithGroups xmlns="http://xxx.cl.xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx/">' +
        '<DuplicateAction>Replace</DuplicateAction>' +
        '<Groups>' +
        '<decimal>' + groupId + '</decimal>' +
        '</Groups>' +
        '<Contacts>' + contacts + '</Contacts>' +
        '<DateFormat>string</DateFormat>' +
    '</ContactBulkImportWithGroups>' +
    '</soap:Body>' +
'</soap:Envelope>'].join('');
```

console.log(contacts)

[image: console.log(contacts)]

soap post payload

[image: payload]

Comment: Have you looked in the browser developer tab to see what the outgoing request from that point looks like?

Comment: Yes the <Contacts><c><f></f><l></l><e></e></c>.... is from the toolbar. CDATA and its content get removed

Comment: That's pretty weird. It looks like that tool uses jQuery `$.parseXML()` to turn the string into an XML DOM. That, in turn, simply uses the native browser facilities to do the real work.

Comment: You think parseFromString is messing with my string?

Comment: When I pass my xml string into $.parseXML the output is ok. it has my CDATA stuff in it

Comment: Hmm. That's really odd.

Comment: its definitely jquery.soap thats doing this. as it happens in beforesend. just can't figure out what

Comment: could this be as a result of some transformation?

Comment: That `.toString()` function in "SOAPObject" looks kind-of suspicious to me, but I'm just reading code so I could be wildly wrong. I would certainly take a sec to put some `console.log()` calls in there, but that's just me.

Comment: Looking at this.toString function cObj has the right body with CDATA in it

Comment: In your XHR what do you see as the value of Content-Type (last screeenshot) ?

Comment: Also I would suggest add 'beforeSend' function as an option to the SOAP object....something like 'options.beforeSend = function(data) { console.log(data); }` and what it shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that jquery.soap is not accounting for `CDATA` elements, in [the current code of the jquery.soap.js file](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap/blob/f642fc079e2d7ea40b2ea1fc12070b068ff0770b/jquery.soap.js), inside the function `dom2soap`, from line 482 to line 488 there is this code:

```
            if (child.nodeType === 1) {
                var childObject = SOAPTool.dom2soap(child);
                soapObject.appendChild(childObject);
            }
            if (child.nodeType === 3 && !whitespace.test(child.nodeValue)) {
                soapObject.val(child.nodeValue);
            }
```

The problem is that the `nodeType` for a `CDATA` element is 4, so your `CDATA` elements are being ignored.

I've forked the original jquery.soap repo, I've created a new branch called `cdata-fix` and I've made a few changes in the jquery.soap.js file that should solve your issue. [You can see those changes here](https://github.com/josepot/jquery.soap/commit/4ebf86b4cc21012e2aedbb64ab27ef81b03dc915#diff-85e01184326c2ae667438b42ecbdc31c).

I've created [this pull request](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap/pull/61) in the jquery.soap repo, hopefully the pull request will be accepted, but in the meanwhile feel free to use my version of the jquery.soap.js, I'm quite confident that it will work just fine.

In **[this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EY0lmyJESSO2FV8j6LIp?p=preview)** you can see that the changes that I've made to the jquery.soap.js file are fixing your issue. (Have a look at the payload of the post with a 404 error)

**UPDATE:**

The pull request [has been accepted](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap/pull/61).

Comment: This is why I like open source and JS. The community

Answer (score 2):

I am the author/maintainer of jquery.soap and I am always striving to get the lib better! Maybe, since this is purely related to jquery.soap, would you mind moving the discussion to github? You can find it at: https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap/ and open an new issue there...

If you don't have an account at github and don't want to make one that's fine by me and we stick to stackoverflow....

I did take a look at the problem you described but I was unable to recreate that scenario. In my testbed the namespace added to Contacts is still there and send to the WebService...

```
<ContactBulkImportWithGroups xmlns="http://xxx.cl.xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx/">
  <DuplicateAction>Replace</DuplicateAction>
  <Groups>
    <decimal>01234</decimal>
  </Groups>
  <Contacts xmlns="http://xxx.c1.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx/">
    <c>
      <f><![CDATA[Remy]]></f>
      <l><![CDATA[Blom]]></l>
      <e><![CDATA[remy.blom@hku.nl]]></e>
    </c>
  </Contacts>
  <DateFormat>string</DateFormat>
</ContactBulkImportWithGroups>
```

This exactly the way the xml goes in and comes out of jquery.soap in my testbed. Maybe you can supply me an example that does go wrong?

**UPDATE**: I now see you are trying to send an empty namespace...... xmlns=""
This indeed needs the change you put in the post. I put the in my code and will publish them tommorow...

Comment: Hi Remy, thank you for your work, it has been quite helpful. I  can confirm that Josep and I both replicated the issue and his solution is indeed targeting the issue and offers a concise solution. Just view his changes in the dom2soap function: if (child.nodeType === 4){ soapObject.val('<![CDATA[' + child.nodeValue + ']]>');} as you have not taken nodetype 4 into account with regards to CDATA

Comment: The changes from Josep are already in the new 1.4.2 version on github. I might not have been clear but I was talking about the issue of the empty namespace you talked about in the other answer you gave. Unfortunately I do not have the reps to comment on that answer and had to add a new answer, confusing... :) Sorry about that. But long story short: thanx for fix! I'll include it in 1.4.3 which will probably be published tomorrow! Best regards!

Comment: New 1.4.3 is up at [github](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap)! Thanx again for the fix!

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer to my own question but important insight.**

I thought I mention one more thing about the plugin's method to assign attributes:

Some API's need empty namespaces and the tool doesn't allow those which breaks the requests.

for example if I want to post `<contacts xmlns="">....` the plugin turns it to `<contacts>....`

The work around was:

```
this.attr = function (name, value) {
    if (!!name && !!value || !!name && value === "") {
        this.attributes[name] = value;
        return this;
    } else if (!!name) {
        return this.attributes[name];
    } else {
        return this.attributes;
    }
};
```